# Non-negativity of integrand

Tags: calculus

I am wondering if the sign-definiteness of an integrand can be inferred from its integral under some conditions. For example, if I have a function $f(x)$ such that

$\int_0^x f(y)dy \geq 0, \forall x \in [0,y^\star] \text{ and } f(0)=0,$ where $y^\star$ is some fixed positive scalar.

then, can I deduce that $f(x) \geq 0$?

EDIT (for the context):

I am reading a paper in which the authors prove that for some function $x(t)$, the following is true:

$\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|^2 \leq -\|x(t)\| (\|x(t)\|-\sigma), \forall t \geq 0$, and some positive scalar $\sigma$. They then claim that the condition $x(0)=0$ then implies that

$\|x(t)\| \leq \sigma, \forall t \geq 0.$ My initial question was an attempt to prove this by integrating the above inequality.

Comment: What do you mean by $y^{\star}$?

Comment: It is some fixed positive scalar, I'll edit the post

Comment: Consider $\int_0^{3\pi} \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x$. This is greater than 0 but $\sin x$ is not greater than 0 for every value across this interval

Comment: No, changing one point doesn't change the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd expand my comment to an answer as I've had a few more ideas. I believe what you're asking is the following:

> Is it true that if we have 
>   $$\int_0^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \geqslant 0$$
>
> for all $x$ in some interval $I$ of the real line, then
>
> $$f(x) \geqslant 0 \quad \forall x \in I?$$
>
> (along with the initial condition that $f(0)=0$)

As shown in the comments this is not true, seen by considering

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{x} \sin{t} \, \mathrm{d}t & = -\cos{t}\; \Big|_0^x  \\
                                  & = 1-\cos{x}
\end{align*}$$

which is clearly greater than or equal to $0$ for all $x$ as $\cos{x}\leqslant 1 \; \forall x\in\Bbb{R}$. However $\sin{x}$ is not always positive ($\sin{\frac{3\pi}{2}} = -1$), hence the hypothesis is incorrect.

Hope this helps, but please do let me know if I've interpreted the question incorrectly)

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is indeed what I was wondering.

Comment: I've edited the original question to provide some context on as to why I asked the original question.